# is this a bug of backbonejs set function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hi I am new to backbonejs,

I have encountered a problem while i was trying an example of http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#validation

I have created an 2 object of model, myTodo and myTodo1,

if I call set function like this, it return completed:false due to validation error

```
    var myTodo  = new Todo();
    myTodo.set('completed', true, {validate: true}); 
    console.log("completed: "+myTodo.get('completed'));
    /*
    The above code returns following log:
    This model has been initialized.
    Remember to set a title for your todo.
    completed: false
    */
```

**buy why validation is not executing on execution of below code**

```
    var myTodo1  = new Todo();
    myTodo1.set('completed',true);
    console.log("completed: "+myTodo1.get('completed'));
    myTodo1.set({validate:true})
    console.log("completed: "+myTodo1.get('completed'));
    /*
    The above code returns following log:
    This model has been initialized. underscore-test2.js:11
    completed: true underscore-test2.js:28
    completed: true 
    */
```

although both set of code doing the same job, but in first case validation executes but not in second case

Why?????

below is the full example code.

```
    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        completed: false,
      },
      validate: function(attribs){
        if(attribs.title === undefined){
            return "Remember to set a title for your todo.";
        }
      },
      initialize: function(){
        console.log('This model has been initialized.');
        this.on("invalid", function(model, error){
            console.log(error);
        });
        this.on('change:title', function(){
            console.log('- Values for title have changed.');
        });
      }
    });

    **var myTodo  = new Todo();
    myTodo.set('completed', true, {validate: true}); 
    console.log("completed: "+myTodo.get('completed'));**

    **var myTodo1  = new Todo();
    myTodo1.set('completed',true);
    console.log("completed: "+myTodo1.get('completed'));
    myTodo1.set({validate:true})
    console.log("completed: "+myTodo1.get('completed'));**
```

Comment: `myTodo1.set({validate:true})` is setting an attribute called `validate` to true.  Try `myTodo1.set({validate:'hello!'}); console.log(myTodo1.get('validate'));` in your code, and you will see this has nothing to do with running your validate function.

Answer (score 1):

They're simply totally different.

```
myTodo1.set({validate:true})
```

Here you're not running the validation. You're simply setting an attribute "validate" to true for the model. So basically, in the second example, you're setting 2 attributes without validating.

In any case, you cannot hope to do the validation afterwards, as your attribute would have already been set.

**Edit:**
I don't know the behavior when setting a new value to the validate attribute though. But you're certainly overriding your validation function by a boolean. This would certainly lead to unexpected behaviors.

**Edit 2:**

Ok, I guess that'll be my last attempt.

```
myTodo1.set({completed:true});
myTodo1.set({validate:true});
```

also equivalent to:

```
myTodo1.set({completed: true}).set({validate: true});
```

**BUT NOT EQUIVALENT, IN ANY CASE, TO:**

```
myTodo1.set({completed: true}, {validate: true});
```

In the lattest, the `{validate: true}` tells Backbone to apply the validation function on the model.

In the former, you only set the *completed attribute* to true **without telling the model to validate**. **THEN** you set the *validate attribute* to true **once again without telling the model to validate**. So basically **you never tell the model to validate**.

Comment: I am also wondering to how to reply to your reply, its not coming in formatted

Comment: Hi @Loamhoof, 

in backbonejs this line of code 

<br><!-- language: lang-js --> 

    myTodo.set('completed', true, {validate: true});  

<br> and this line of code doing the same job,  

<br> <!-- language: lang-js -->

    myTodo.set({completed:true}, {validate: true}); 

 

I am wondering if I call set function on second object two time, why the job is not being done.

    myTodo1.set({completed:true});
    
    myTodo1.set({validate:true})

Comment: I agree with you, the 2 pieces of code you wrote in your comment ARE identical. But `myTodo1.set({completed:true}); myTodo1.set({validate:true})` is completely different from `myTodo.set({completed:true}, {validate: true});`... Here you are just setting the completed attribute to true, then setting the validate attribute to true...

Comment: No in this line
myTodo.set({completed:true}, {validate: true})
validation gets executed,

if so then it should also execute with following code as well
myTodo1.set({completed:true});
 myTodo1.set({validate:true})